# Call a function periodically in angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have an angular controller which displays a backgroud image and text message. The controller is:

```
var myArchiveController = function($scope) {

     var setBackground = function() {
         $scope.backgroundUrl = someUrlFromService;
         $scope.backgroundMessage = someMessageFromService;
     }

     setBackground();
}

app.controller("myController", myController);
```

How can I call the `setBackground()` function periodically, e.g. every minute?

Comment: wrap `setBackground` with an [`$interval`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$interval)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use angular $[interval](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$interval) service:

```
var myArchiveController = function($scope, $interval) {

    var setBackground = function() {
        $scope.backgroundUrl = someUrlFromService;
        $scope.backgroundMessage = someMessageFromService;
    }

    $scope.intervalIstance = $interval(setBackground, 60000);
}
```

To stop it Arbitrarily, use $interval.cancel.

```
$interval.cancel($scope.intervalIstance);
```

Don't forget to include $interval it in your dependencies.

Answer (score 2):

The following should do it for you.

```
setInterval(setBackground, 60000);
```

or else, and the **preferred** approach, is to use angular's `$interval` service - `$interval(setBackground, 60000);`

You will need to inject the interval service (`$interval`) into the controller and then the code will be as follows:

```
var myArchiveController = function($scope, $interval) {

   //code here

    $interval(setBackground, 60000);
}
```